# How to paginate results with Tire gem and WillPaginate in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, ruby-on-rails-4, will-paginate, tire

I have just begun implementing the Tire gem & ElasticSearch into my Rails 4 app. On the [Tire gem home page](https://github.com/karmi/tire), it states:

```
Note that Tire search results are fully compatible with WillPaginate and Kaminari, so you can pass all the usual parameters to the search method in the controller:

    @articles = Article.search params[:q], :page => (params[:page] || 1)
```

I have pretty much the exact same setup:

```
  @projects = Project.search params[:query], :load => true, :page => (params[:page] || 1)
```

When I try to search I get:

```
undefined method `total_pages' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

**Project.rb:**

```
  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  settings :analysis => {
      :filter  => {
          :ngram_filter => {
              :type => "nGram",
              :min_gram => 2,
              :max_gram => 12
          }
      },
      :analyzer => {
          :index_ngram_analyzer => {
              :type  => "custom",
              :tokenizer  => "standard",
              :filter  => ["lowercase", "ngram_filter"]
          },
          :search_ngram_analyzer => {
              :type  => "custom",
              :tokenizer  => "standard",
              :filter  => ["standard", "lowercase", "ngram_filter"]
          }
      }
  } do
    mapping do
      indexes :id, :type => 'integer'
      indexes :title
      indexes :description
    end
  end
```

How can I properly paginate search results using WillPaginate? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have a feeling this is a Rails 4 issue. I have also tried the exact setup used in the Railscasts in my app, and am getting the same error. When I load the source code for the Railscast in Rails 3, everything works. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like both WillPaginate and Kaminari are compatible with Rails 4:

- https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/commit/4289490
- https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/commit/96e2d75

However, new versions haven't been released to Rubygems. You have to point your Gemfile to the Github repository:

```
# Either:
gem "will_paginate", git: 'https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate.git'
# Or:
gem "kaminari", git: 'https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari.git'
```

Pagination should work. If you want to try it out on an isolated case, generate a new Rails 4 with the template provided by Tire and play with it:

```
rails new rails4app -m https://raw.github.com/karmi/tire/master/examples/rails-application-template.rb
cd rails4app

# Change articles_controller.rb to:
@articles = Article.tire.search params[:q], page: params[:page]

COUNT=1000 rake db:seed
rails server
```

Comment: Thanks, karmi, this fixed my problem. Tire is a great gem btw!

Comment: Cool, glad it's been sorted out!